# why does my code return ReferenceError: tea is not defined when i choose tea?

Tags: javascript

i'm currently coding some javascript, and i'm stuck. here's the code:

```
var options = confirm ("Here's our menu. we have chicken, rice, eggs (boiled, fried or served uncooked), meat (choose your type of meat (you can take it raw, sauced or pre-cooked)), tea, coffee, some sweets (galaxy, all types (crunchy, hazelnut, plain, almond, caramel and flutes (flutes with 1-pair and 2-pairs)), and we have grocery if you need.")
var choice = prompt ("Choose the item that you want.")
var addon = prompt ("Would you like any additional thing to your order?")
var amount = prompt ("How much do you want from the item you requested?")
var addonAmount = prompt ("How much additional items would you like for your order?")
switch (choice && addon && amount && addonamount) {
    case 'chicken':
        if (choice === "chicken" && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0) {
            console.log("Okay. " + amount + " " + choice + "with " + addonAmount + addon + " coming right up!")
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, but i didn't hear your request properly.")
        }
    case 'rice':
        if (choice === rice && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0) {
            console.log("Okay. " + amount + " " + choice + "with " + addonAmount + addon + " coming right up!")
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, but i didn't hear your request properly.")
        }
    case 'tea':
        if (choice === tea && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0) {
            console.log("Okay. " + amount + " " + choice + "with " + addonAmount + addon + " coming right up!")
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, but i didn't hear your request properly.")
        }
            default:
        console.log("Sorry, but the items you requested was not found.")
}
```

*note that the code is still flawed
EDIT: i revamped the code, but it still flawed, and i need help.

soo, what's the error making line in the code, and how could i fix it? thanks. any suggestions on code optimization would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this switch statement is going to work as you expect. You should also make yourself more familiar with logical operators and their precedence. I recommend to consult a JavaScript guide. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators . For example, `"yes" && amount > 0` will always result in `"yes"`. The rest of the expression is not even evaluated.

Comment: Semicolons are your friend.

Comment: And `console.log` doesn't return anything, so `response` is definitely not an array, it's just `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling i already know much about logical operators. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling soo, what should i use if i want to define an array? sorry, i'm a newbie.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object . And no, it seems you still have to learn (more) about logical operators. See the example in my first comment. I assume that's not the behavior you want. Especially if you are new, you should read that guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that stand out to me to help you get rid of your bugs. I'm not clear on what logic you want to follow for your switch, but I will point out some things you should change to avoid behavior that you might not be expecting.

First thing is in the switch statement signature has a series variables separated by && operators. This will cause the last variable to be evaluated to become your 'case.' It looks like the your 'case' will be `addonAmount`; however it looks like you might just want it to be `choice`. You should just put `choice` in the signature by itself because if any of those values are false, it will just return false instead.

It should look like this:

`switch (choice) { ... }`

(also, you have a typo: `addonamount` should be `addonAmount` but if you just take that out it won't matter anymore)

Secondly, you need to make sure that you put a `break;` after every case otherwise it will run the next case even if the criteria has not been met.

That should look like this:

```
case 'chicken':
        if (choice === "chicken" && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0) {
            console.log("Okay. " + amount + " " + choice + "with " + addonAmount + addon + " coming right up!")
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, but i didn't hear your request properly.")
        }
        break; //make sure you do this at the end of every case block
case 'rice':
```

It looks like you are referencing tea as a variable and not a string here:

`if (choice === tea && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0) ...`

Your error is saying that tea is not defined is because you do not have a variable named tea defined. `tea` should be a string, not a variable which means that you surround it with quotes. When you leave a series of letters in JavaScript without quotes around it, it tries to parse it as a variable unless it is a special JavaScript keyword (like `function`, `var`, `switch`, etc)

Try this instead:

`if (choice === "tea" && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0) ...`

Also, you have the same error for the "rice" selection:

`if (choice === rice && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0)...`

Should be:

`if (choice === 'rice' && addon === "no" && amount > 0 && addonAmount > 0)`

More information on switch statements can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

If your code still is not doing what you expect, it probably lies in the if statement signature where you are doing a series of && operators again. What happens is that it will only enter into that if block if all those conditions return a truthy value.

Just a last note that you should be consistent with your choice of quotes. If you want to do single or double, it doesn't matter as long as you use the same ones (or if you work at a company it should be the same as the rest of the codebase).

I hope those changes help you get closer to your goal!

Comment: okay, thanks for your humble answer. you made the facepalm of my day. also, check the rice word at the corrected rice statement, not surrounded by quotes.